# вывод текста из базы данных

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

здравствуйте, как выводить текст из базы данных без лишних пробелов и переносов?

Пробывал функцию n2lbr - не помогает, можно между двумя строками хоть 100 переносов сделать

см. скриншот
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так что сделать-то нужно?

Answer (score 1):

Ответ уже есть [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760816/remove-new-lines-from-string):

```
$string = trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $string));
```

Альтернатива без регулярных выражений (всё оттуда же):

```
$string = str_replace(array("\r\n","\r"),"",$string);
```

Comment: текст вообще тогда во многих случаях без переноса выводится, а мне нужно просто нормально его вывести, как он выводится здесь, в вк, на всех сайтах, без лишнего пустого места

Comment: Ваш вопрос про "нормально" - это только ваше представление о нормальности. Будьте конкретнее, что вы имеете в виду под "нормально"? Правильно поставленный вопрос - уже половина ответа, поставьте его правильно, т.е "есть вот это, нужно вот это, как это превратить в алгоритм"

Comment: мне нужно было вывести текст с максимальным разрывом в 2 новые строки, вот что мне нужно было

$text = nl2br(preg_replace('~(?:\r?\n){2,}~',"\n\n",trim($text)));

Comment: вот как в ВК выводятся записи на стенах  и личные сообщения, так и мне нужно было